# 3D plot using rxplot

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the messages /master_position   with x, y, z

so I using command

```
rxplot -M 3d /master_position/x /master_position/y /master_position/z
```

or

```
rxplot -M 3d /master_position/x:y:z
```

but it didn't work and got this error

```
rxplot: error: You may only specific 2 or 3 topics with '3d' or 'scatter'.
When 2 topics are provided, time is used as the third axis.
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10261/3d-plot-using-rxplot/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: bug is now closed, will be included in next release.

This is filed as a bug here:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3376

I'm hoping to get time later this week to close out some rxplot tickets.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

^^

I got the solution already,

by debugging I figure out that in file *rxplot_main.py*  in package rxtools has an bug
in line 90 and 92 , I comment out these line

```
 #if len(flat_topics) < 2 or len(flat_topics) > 3:
 #parser.error("You may only specific 2 or 3 topics with '3d' or 'scatter'.\nWhen 2 topics are provided, time is used as the third axis.")
```

and plot

rxplot -M 3d /master_position/x:y:z

work very well

---

Originally posted by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) with karma: 121 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1